# Python: requests.get ignores the last record

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my code:

```
response = requests.get(apiurl+'api/v1/watch/services',
                         auth=(apiuser,apipass), verify=False, stream=True)
for line in response.iter_lines():
    try:
        data = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
        pprint.pprint(data)
    except Exception as e:
        pprint.pprint(e)
        pass
```

Please note the `stream=True`.

The problem is, when I have `a` `b` `c` `d` on the input, the script just outputs `a` `b` and `c`. Then, when `e` comes on input, the script outputs `d`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Except is missing? (show full code please)

Comment: If you print `response.text()` does it include the lines? How about using curl? Is the `Content-Length:` header properly set?

Comment: I think you may have just hit [this bug](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2433), that I filed back in February 2015.

Comment: Before `e` becomes available, does `d` end with a newline?

Comment: @WayneWerner yes it does; works well with curl.

Comment: @jwodder yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer is a bit unexpected for me.

Updating python from 3.4 to 3.5 helped, nothing else changed.

Hope this answer helps someone else fighting this problem.